# How to fix this UV map?

Tags: uv

[image]

I am not very good with UV maps and I have had zero luck unwrapping this guitar correctly and it looks awful. I even added seams.

Comment: you can choose the top view and unwrap from view for example

Comment: I understand and I experimented with each but they all ended up looking awful.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I am not really comfortable with that since I plan on selling the model if that makes sense.

Comment: I understand but I don't get why unwrap from view doesn't work  :/

Comment: It strecthes what is not in view which is not ideal.

Comment: only select the neck and unwrap from view, choose other methods for the other parts, you can also mark seams then simply unwrap

Comment: Alright. Thanks I am just going to mess around with it until im happy.

Comment: You'll probably have an easier time if you separate the fretboard from the frets, the headstock, and the nut and then unwrap each separately.  The fretboard's just a cube after all.

Comment: Would  you by any chance know how to fix an issue im having? My UVs are very low resolution when a 4k texture is applied because the UV maps are no big enough even though i made sure to fill the entire UV grid. How do I fix this and make the map higher resolution without scaling out of the UV box?